# Finding sufficient statistic for Weibull density function

Tags: sufficient-statistics, umvue, rao-blackwell

I am given the follow problem and am having trouble finding the sufficient statistic.

Suppose that *Y$_1$*, *Y$_2$*, ..., *Y$_n$* denote a Weibull density function, given by:

*f* ( *y* | $\theta$ ) =

> Let $Y_1, Y_2, ... , Y_n$ denote a Weibull density function, given by:
>   $$
> f (y | \theta ) =
> \begin{cases}
> \frac{2y}{\theta}e^\frac{-y^2}{\theta},  & 0 < y \\
> 0, & \text{elsewhere}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Find the MVUE for $\theta$.

My issue here is again, in regards to finding the sufficient statistic. I begin by taking the likelihood:

L ($\theta$) = $\prod \frac{2y}{\theta}e^\frac{-y^2}{\theta}$

= $(\frac{2}{\theta})^n e^\frac{-\sum{y_i^2}}{\theta}\prod y_i$

How do I know what the sufficient statistic is? Is it:

1. $\prod y_i$
2. $-\sum{y_i^2}$

The answer is supposed to be the second one, but I'm still unclear as to how we know that. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Try taking the log of the likelihood.  Which term now appears to be a constant, i.e., one whose value can change without affecting which value of $\theta$ will maximize the log likelihood?  Which term's value affects  which value of $\theta$ will maximize the log likelihood?

Comment: You can use the exponential family to get the sufficient stat.
In this case 2 is the answer Try to write it in the exponential family and it will be clear to you

Comment: @jbowman Ahh, yes, I see it when I take the log likelihood. My only concern is that we technically learned this method before learning the log likelihood, so I am looking for a way to understand the problem assuming I don't yet know that.

Comment: Well, taking the log is hardly a big deal, but I see what you mean.  The logic you can use is that all $\Pi y_i$ does is scale the likelihood up and down, so to speak, it doesn't change its shape - or, more importantly, where the maximum is with respect to $\theta$.  Sort of like that $2^n$ term at the front of the expression; you can include it or not, but it won't affect the shape or where the maximum is.  This is not true of the other term $-\Sigma y_i^2$.

Comment: @jbowman Okay I think I get it now. So basically the reason -$\sum{y_i^2}$ is sufficient is because it's behavior is affected by the parameter, which in turn is a function of the likelihood? Sorry that was kind of awkwardly worded.

Comment: Yes, it's just an intuitive, verbal way of describing what @Deep North's answer below says more mathematically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the Neyman factorization theorem it is quite clear the second option is the sufficient statistic.

Just review the theorem,

> Let $X_1,X_2,...X_n $ denote a random sample from a distribution that
>   has $\textit{pdf}$ or $\textit{pmf}$ of $f(x;\theta), \theta \in \Omega$. The statistic
>   $Y_1 = u_1(X_1 , ... ,X_n)$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$ if
>   and only if we can find two nonnegative functions, $k_1$ and $k_2$ such
>   that $$f(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n;\theta) = k_1[ u_1(x_1, x_2, ... ,
>  x_n);\theta ] k_2(x_1, x_2, ... , x_n)$$
>
> where:
>
> $k_1$ is a function that depends on the data $x_1, x_2, ..., x_n$ only
>   through the function $u_1(x_1, x_2,..., x_n)$, and the function
>   $k_2(x_1, x_2, ..., x_n)$ does not depend on the parameter $\theta$

Now look at your $L(\theta)$, the first part is $(\frac{2}{\theta})^n e^\frac{-\sum{y_i^2}}{\theta}$  this is the $k_1$ function, it depends on $ y_1, y_2,...,y_n $ only through $-\sum y_i^2$ (note, you should treat $\theta$ as a constant here, since you condition on it here). The second part is $\prod y_i$ which does not depend on $\theta$, it is the $k_2$ function.

So by the factorization theorem, you can directly say $-\sum y_i^2$ is the sufficient statistic for $\theta$.

Comment: Ahh I see. So $\sum{y_i^2}$ is the sufficient statistic because e$^\frac{\sum{y_i^2}}{\theta}$ is a function of both the data and the parameter? ..... Or actually wait. If this is the case, why can't $\frac{2^n}{\theta^n} e^\frac{1}{\theta}  \prod y_i$ be k1 and $e^\sum{y_i^2}$ be k2 ?. If so, k1 is still a function of the data and parameter and k2 only includes the data.

Comment: $e^{\frac{\sum{y_i^2}}{\theta}}\neq e^{\frac{1}{\theta}}e^{\sum{y_i^2}}$

Comment: Ahh I've gotten way too far along in math to make that mistake, Thank you